# Delete Firebase Data after set time, regardless of app termination

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to allow my users to set an expiration timer (up to 2 hours) for data stored in Firebase. The data needs to be deleted once the timer expires, but I've been having trouble finding a solution that will accomplish this **even if the app is terminated**. The timer is also displayed to the user and needs to be kept up to speed when the user re-opens the app. Also, other users shouldn't be able to see the data if it expired while the creator's app was terminated.

The only thing I could think of was using timestamp comparisons, which seems really inefficient. What's the best approach to this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no server-side time-to-live support in the Firebase Database. You'll have to run a script (client-side or on your own "server"). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours

Comment: does each user have their own timer and data? In other words, can users see each other's data and/or set a timer for other users?

Comment: Users can see each others data (assuming it hasn't expired) but cannot set a timer for other users.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is that still the case today?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that you can now run such a script on Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply. I haven't found a how-to or tutorial to build such a script (also in the Firebase Documentation). Can you please link us to one or tell us how to do it in an answer? Appreciate it! It'd be very useful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The only thing I found is this useless answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772618/5113094

Comment: Interesting. Because that answer is precisely what I used when I recently needed to do scheduled maintenance with a Cloud Function. Between that answer (also presented in [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) and mentioned in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)) and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours) you have all the necessary parts.

Comment: If you're having problems making it work, share the [minimal steps to reproduce that problem in a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).