# Run timer on Firebase servers using Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to implement a Firebase server-side countdown timer (example: 10 hour countdown) in Android Studio using the new **Cloud Functions**?

I want the timer to be server side, meaning that whenever a user opens my app the counter will always be at the same time for all users.

Comment: I'm curious to see what more **Cloud Functions** have to offer.

Comment: You don't really need a Cloud Function to share data between users.  You could simply store the final time when the timer expires in the database that everyone can read but no one can write.  BTW, Cloud Functions is not integrated into Android Studio.  It doesn't care what IDE you use to build your app.

Comment: @DougStevenson My goal is to avoid tampering with the device's (client side) current time. That's why I need a server-side timer.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do.  If you want to show a running count of time remaining until some point of time in the future, you pretty much have to depend on the clock of the local device, and use that to compute the time remaining.

Comment: @DougStevenson Indeed. That's what I want to do: _show a running count of time remaining until some point of time in the future_. Can't I depend on the clock of the Firebase server, and use the server to compute the time remaining?

Comment: The best thing you have available is this, but I can't say if it's accurate enough for your needs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Functions does not currently provide timers / cron-like jobs.

You could emulate the behavior using a ping service or something like https://cron-job.org, that said this is probably still a good use for a "traditional" Google AppEngine Instance + the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Firebase scheduled functions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Example:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

OR

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```