# How to automatically delete a user in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**CODE:**

app.js

```
setInterval(function() {

    console.log("1");
    var pendingRef = admin.database().ref("pending");
    var now = Date.now();
    var cutoff = now - 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var old = pendingRef.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff).limitToLast(1);
    console.log("2");
    var listener = old.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        console.log("3");
        console.log("A VALUE:"+snapshot.val());
        snapshot.delete().then(function() {
            snapshot.ref().remove();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("USER WAS NOT DELETED:"+ snapshot.val().key);
        });
    });
}, 1000 * 10);
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I call it at the end of my `app.js`

Nothing happens.

Nothing gets printed to the console after "1" and "2".

---

**EDIT:**

I cannot call `.remove()` on a `snapshot`.

Also, from the docs:

"To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently. See Re-authenticate a user."

How can I delete a user then ?

---

**REFERENCE:**

[Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: If you set up a minimal jsbin that reproduces the problem I'll have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How can I do that when admin credentials are needed ? EDIT: Also, I tried with another firebase func like once("value") and that one worked. I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://jsbin.com/yijalokalu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Putting the code from your question in a jsbin does not help. You will have to spend the effort to reproduce the problem, which seems to be attaching a dynamic query. If you can't reproduce it in a jsbin, I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no `delete` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) on the snapshot. Instead, you should just call `remove` on the snapshot's `ref`:

```js
var listener = old.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  console.log("EXECUTING...");
  console.log("A VALUE:" + snapshot.val());
  snapshot.ref
    .remove()
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("USER WAS NOT DELETED:" + snapshot.key);
    });
});
```

To delete the user account - in addition to the user data you have stored - you also need to call the [`deleteUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteUser) method (as you are running this on Node using `firebase-admin`):

```js
var listener = old.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  console.log("EXECUTING...");
  console.log("A VALUE:" + snapshot.val());
  snapshot.ref
    .remove()
    .then(function () {
      return admin.auth().deleteUser(snapshot.key);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("USER WAS NOT DELETED:" + snapshot.key);
    });
});
```

Comment: I still need to delete the user in the authentication system though. I can't call that method on the snaphot, so how can I call that method ?

Comment: You call it on a `User` instance. There's no point calling it on the snapshot if it's a user method.

Comment: I know, but how do I do it then ?

Comment: Fixed an error in the answer re: `snapshot.ref` - it's a property, not a method - but it's not possible to answer your question about deleting the user's account without more information. Are you running this on Node - using `firebase-admin`? And where in the snapshot's data is the account's `uid`? Without it, you cannot delete the account.

Comment: I updated my question. I am using firebase-admin and the uid is the key of the snapshot.

Comment: Updated the answer with `deleteUser`.

Comment: This is extremely strange. Only 1 and 2 get printed to the console. But not 3. The firebase function is not triggered.

Comment: TypeError: firebase.auth(...).deleteUser is not a function

Comment: Please modify your answer: it should be admin.auth().deleteUser(...) so I can accept it.