# Firebase Cloud Function to remove data automatically after specific time

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to delete any data that is older that two hours. I know this question is already answered here [Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours)

Answer is:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/path/to/items/');
var now = Date.now();
var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var old = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff).limitToLast(1);
var listener = old.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().remove();
});
```

But can someone help in converting it to nodejs function which i can deploy to firebase cloud function.

Comment: Blog post the specifically addresses this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html.  See also this [Cloud Functions sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Function is like a trigger in database, it needs event to stimulate the function to do the works.

The info for all the events can be looked at [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers).

For your case, I suggest using [http event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http)

After that, you can make a cron job from your own server, or GAE, or anything else that call a http request to trigger your function.

Comment: This is exactly right. You'll want to use a cron job. I've had success using an Cloud Function with Zapier. Zapier lets you fire off HTTP requests or push data to Firebase on a cron.