# How to remove a child or a specific child generated by push(), Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need to delete a child, What I am looking for is erasing, in order of time,

Example, i the user select "PostDuration" 3Days , I need the post to be deleted in the selected duration

the uid method:

```
   public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

My childs that containt the data its generated by this method:

```
     FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(FirebaseUtils.getUid).setValue(mPost);
```

the ref:

```
    public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("posts");
}
```

[image: photo]

my Database structure

Comment: Please ensure that the code you share actually compiles. There is no way that `FirebaseUtils.getUid` now compiles, as its missing parentheses. Aside from that, the approach is similar to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours. I'd recommend translating that approach to Android and posting your (compiling) code if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen how can i Add timeStamp value to a my childrens? i can delete this with the "n" days?

Comment: Here's one way: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps