# Is there a way to delete or edit something on the Firebase Database in swift after certain time?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want a way please to delete, change, or edit values automatically after a certain time in the database of the Firebase in swift.

Comment: We will need to see your attempt at fixing your problem before we as a community can help. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @scb998 often wanna say it to some users..

Comment: The Firebase Database does not have a built-in time-to-live. Here's an answer where I showed how to do something like that in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours

Comment: Thank you for your help but i am beginner and i only know swift. Please Do you know how to make it in swift ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Doesn't that snippet of code need to be run manually from time to time (from a client)? There are ways of automating that task with cloud functions. Please see [What Can I Do with Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance). You won't be able to do this task with Swift directly, however, you can leverage a service like Zapier to assist with cron jobs.

Comment: Hey Jay. The code is the same between a JavaScript client and a Cloud Function. And unfortunately there are no cron-job/time-triggered Cloud Functions yet. :-/