# Node doesn't get removed from Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following data structure:

[image]

Unfortunately, 'days' does not get removed from the database with the code below.

My current code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

     exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/path/to/items/{pushId}') //irrelevant to the question
    .onWrite(event => {
      var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
      var now = Date.now();
      var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);

  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  }).then(function() {;
    return functions.database.ref('/days').remove(); // /days doesn't get removed!
  });

    });
```

Comment: Did you try without slash and child method? 
functions.database.ref.child('days').remove();

Comment: @MaduraPradeep Yes, I tried that. It doesn't work. Bounty will be immediately awarded to the answer that solves the issue!

Comment: Instead of Firebase functions, use Firebase class.

ref = new Firebase("myfirebase.com");
ref.child(key).remove();

Comment: @MaduraPradeep I want to delete the 'days' node only.

Comment: days is not your root node right?

Comment: @MaduraPradeep No

Comment: @MaduraPradeep as you can see in the image

Comment: Then this should work.

ref = new Firebase("myfirebase.com"); 

ref.child('days').remove();

Comment: @MaduraPradeep Nope. Still not working. Maybe you should write a complete answer to make things clearer.

Comment: Could you add your full Firebase data structure?

Comment: @MaduraPradeep I updated the question. Of course, I can't upload the real structure for privacy reasons.

Comment: Does the code before "execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function" get executed?

Comment: @jaibatrik Yes, because it performs what it's intended to do, it's originally from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012520/7889746

Comment: @jaibatrik That's why I put 100+ bounty. Because, the issue is complicated. I put up most of my reputation for that bounty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let updates = {};
updates['/days'] = null;

firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

See "Updating or deleting data" in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write);

In your code:

```
.then(function() {;
    let updates = {};
    updates['/days'] = null;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
});
```

**Edit: Try something like this:**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const defaultDatabase = admin.database();

...

let updates = {};
updates['/days'] = null;
defaultDatabase.ref().update(updates);
```

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start