# update database firebase realtime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I am planing to create an application, and am new to android.

I am using Firebase as backend and i am trying yo update and score every time the users win.

I am using this and the app crashes:

```
public void updatescore (){
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String uid = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
    final DatabaseReference mostafa = ref.child(uid);


    mostafa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int saldo2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            saldo saldoide = new saldo(saldo2 + 100);
            mostafa.setValue(saldoide);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

my db is very simple :

```
KQSxF0e901gCPwgu2npvAm0BsKy2

 saldo2: 0
```

Code:

```
 if (ejugador1.equals("paper") && ejugador2.equals("stone")){
        resultado = "You Win";
                        updatescore ()
    }
```

Comment: can you share the error trace message?

Comment: @RohitPadma com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int

Comment: Try this line  :-                                                                                                int saldo2 = Integer.valueof(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

Comment: @RohitPadma the previous error dissapear , but now i have this one: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{saldo2=0}"

Comment: dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()  is returning {saldo2=0} so you cannot convert that to integer.  So Modified code so change this line :-                                                                                                 final DatabaseReference mostafa = ref.child(uid).child('saldo2');

Comment: @RohitPadma the first time i win is works , but the secound time crashes with this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{saldo2=100}" (Every time you win 100 points are added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
int saldo2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

with

```
int saldo2 = dataSnapshot.child("saldo2").getValue(Integer.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Alex, remember me? :) Can you please take a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743530/node-with-more-than-1-child-is-not-getting-removed Nobody's giving an answer even after setting a +50 bounty...

Comment: Yes, i remember but unfortunately i don't know Javascript. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code :-

```
   int saldo2 = Integer.valueof(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

Comment: the previous error dissapear , but now i have this one: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{saldo2=0}"

Comment: @ChrisDopazo   dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()  is returning {saldo2=0}  as string so you cannot convert that to integer.  So try this line :-                                                                                                 final DatabaseReference mostafa = ref.child(uid).child('saldo2');

Comment: the first time i win is works , but the secound time crashes with this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{saldo2=100}" (Every time you win 100 points are added)