# Delete older firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete data older than 2 hours. I tried another SO answer but it did not solve my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012520/2872091

Now, let me show my code and firebase structure

**Firebase Structure:**

[image: image1]

**Index.js:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('Room/English/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {

  var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('time').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);

  });
});
```

Then, I deployed this js file to my firebase.

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

It is deployed successfully, terminal said "**Deploy complete!**". And I can see *deleteOldItems* function in Firebase functions.

As a result, my structure and code is like this. And nothing changed when a new data is added to Room/English node. Data (older than 2 hours) in this node is not deleted. How can I solve the problem? What is my mistake?

Comment: The signature for Cloud Functions has change. I updated my original answer, and will close your question against that again. Note that this change is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database and that the sample repo is linked is also updated: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr Puffelen. You solved my problem :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/path/to/items/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why did you like this? Wrong answer! my child is time, besides I think, my path is Room/English/{pushId}