# automatically delete an information on firebase based on android date

Tags: android, firebase

I have an app that the client can put their events, parties and etc, putting the event's start date and event end date, so I want the app to delete the event as it passes tend date, not to accumulate events that have already happened, someone Have you done something like this before? to using firebase.

Comment: I think you can try firebase cloud functions to run some methods periodically in the server, or run the delete method to delete records before today when the user opens the app every time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours

Comment: This link is java script, but I will study and use as an example. Is there another link, for android?