# firebase real time database validating rules

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In realtime database I have child `bus_id` & its nodes are `bus_no`, `bus_id`, `bus_time` and `creationDate` as a timestamp. Already I have sorting data using `orderBychild(timestamp)`. I have also implement create/add `bus_id` if `bus_id` not exists using rule `!data.exists && newData.exists()`.

Now I want To implement that, update child `bus_id` if it's created 10 minutes before **or** update `child` bus_id if it having timestamp 10 minutes before.

And i will updating data by `ref.child(bus_id).setValue(busInfo);`

So is there query for invalidating above problem by using ternary operator?

Comment: Maybe [this link to the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables) will point you in the right direction, there is a variable called `now` that provides access to the current server time.... so your database will have to include a "*last_modified_datetime*", and compare that against the server time... and see if the difference is less than 10 minutes.

Comment: thankss for replaying but by using timestamp can we write invalidating rule for create/add record or data if not exist and update data/record if it has timestamp before 10. minnute before..??? & how??

Comment: Yes, you can. Unfortunately I don't have the time to hand-hold you through the whole development process, you'll have to figure that out yourself.... but yes, this will work.

Comment: sir it has single query like !data.exists() || data.exist()...... like that.. but i am confusing, how to implement it in single using operators like !,&&, || so please can you help me what should i do , it must updated if it's timestamp before 10 min...??? i am wating for your reply...

Comment: @ShivamGupta: Your description of your code is hard to parse. Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Having an MCVE is by far the best way to increase the chances that somebody can help with concrete coding problems such as yours.

Comment: @ShivamGupta did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

What I can make out from your question is that, you want to update `bus_id` child if it has been created 10 mins before otherwise update that `bus_id` which was created 10 mins ago.

I can suggest you two ways to do so, first is by adding a new timestamp with name `timeCreated` for every `bus_id`, then you can retrieve their value, and check if it is 10 mins old or not.

This can let you update the `bus_id` which is 10 minutes older.

Another way is by by altering the Firebase rules according to your need, as @JeremyW said in the comments.

Some useful resources for that will be, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI), which you should skip to the time **22:55**.

[Firebase docs regarding this.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32004582).

Comment: You can simply use this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI#t=22m55s) :)