# Replace firebase data with functions each X period?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an firebase firestore database where stored information about bets.

I haven't any back end, only SPA/Vue.js <---> Firebase.

I need to update bets status each X minutes automatically, using for that external API data.

Is there any way to do that without server using only firebase (cloud functions maybe)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that would indeed be with Cloud Functions. Have a look at the documentation for [running functions periodically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), the sample for [deleting unused accounts](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron), this question [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time), and this example for [deleting outdated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours) (although that triggers on database writes, so you'll have to modify that).

Comment: Thanks for advice, gonna check it now.