# Firebase auto deleting function deleting element in secs when asked to delete after 2 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I couldn't figure what am I doing wrong so need an extra eye to figure out what am I doing wrong.
I am trying out one the question's answer from [Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours) which uses https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes and https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-old-child-nodes/functions/index.js to delete a node after a time.

```
/root
  /items
    LoHgJSFt8hHi2o_hP: {
      timestamp: 1497911193083,
      ...some_other_data
    },
    LoHgJSsGGHi2o_fD: {
      timestamp: 1597911193083  
      ...some_other_data                  
    }
```

My `index.js` looks like

```
//index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { createUser } = require('./auth/onCreate');
const { deleteOldData } = require('./auth/onDeleteOldData');
const serviceAccount = require('./ownerstown-admin.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://ownexxxxxxxx-c86cf.firebaseio.com'
});
exports.createUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(createUser);
exports.deleteOldData = functions.database.ref('/referralIds/ids/{pushId}').onWrite(deleteOldData);
```

and then `onDeleteOldData.js`

```
// auth/onDeleteOldData.js
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
async function deleteOldData(change) {
  console.log('starting nooowwwwwww');
  const ref = change.after.ref.parent;
  console.log('ref', ref);
  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');
  console.log('snapshot', snapshot);
  const updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  return ref.update(updates);
}
module.exports = {
  deleteOldData
};
```

and pushing the data in a button click like

```
  function createLoginId() {
    const rootRef = Firebase.database.ref();
    const allDetails = rootRef.child('referralIds/ids');
    const timeStamp = Date.now();
    const someId = uuidv4();
    const { origin } = window.location;
    const data = {
      timeStamp,
      someId,
      createrId: id
    };
    const newRef = allDetails.push();
    newRef.set(data);
  }
```

But as soon as I push the data, it gets deleted in secs.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your code is divided in two files with an export/import?

Comment: Yes! it's divided into two files.
Just for keeping my index.js clear.

Comment: Can you add to your question the exact content of the two files and not only some snippets. The code in the Function works correctly so it is maybe due to the modularization.

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know if I can add more info to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that when you write to the database you do

```
const timeStamp = Date.now();
//...
const data = {
  timeStamp,
  someId,
  createrId: id
};
```

which means that you save a field `timeStamp`, but your Cloud Function selects the node(s) to be deleted based on `timestamp` (all in lower case).

Node names in the Realtime Database are case sensitive.

---

BTW, note that for the timestamp you could use

```
const timestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

which is "a placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp **as determined by the Firebase servers**", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue

Comment: Right! Damn, That was the issue, the casing. Thanks a ton :)