# Auto/self delete or mark deleted to 1minute old data in real-time firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make auto/self delete or mark data with deleted of 1 minute old data. But I failing to make it in firebase realtime database.

Can anyone help me to make it in firebase nodejs app.

I am trying to create nodejs function as Time-To-Live(TTL) functionality.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This topic has been covered quite regularly before like in https://stackoverflow.com/q/32004582, which even led to a Cloud Functions example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes. I'd recommend reading some of those approaches and trying this yourself. If you get stuck along the way, post back with what you tried and we can probably help better.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Database doesn't have a TTL feature.  You will have to build this yourself.  One approach is to use Cloud Functions in tandem with Cloud Tasks to schedule a task to run 1 minute after you write a child in the database, which would invoke the function to delete it.

I have a more [complete and detailed explanation](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) of how that works with Firestore, but you will have to substitute Realtime Database for Firestore.

Comment: Realtime is must for me to use... But thanks for your quick response.

Comment: As I said, you can adapt the strategy to work with Realtime Database instead of Firestore. Everything else stays the same.

Comment: Ah.. got your point.. thanks