# Get the uid of a value

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I would like to delete files from my storage.

And for that I need the UID from the request `ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);`

I already have a function for deleting child nodes, but I want to delete at the same time the picture in my storage.

Screenshot of my database :

[image]

My cloud functions for Firebase ( I found the code here [Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours) and here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes ) :

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "gs://XXXXX.appspot.com",
});

var defaultStorage = admin.storage();

// Cut off time. Child nodes older than this will be deleted.
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 Hours in milliseconds.

/**
 * This database triggered function will check for child nodes that are older than the
 * cut-off time. Each child needs to have a `timestamp` attribute.
 */
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/images/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');


  // EDIT#2

  snapshot.forEach((child) => {

        const uid = child.key;
        const re = admin.database().ref('images/'+uid);
        const img = re.child('image');

        const bucket = defaultStorage.bucket();
        const file = bucket.file(img);

    // Delete the file
        return file.delete();
    })

  // END EDIT#2

  // create a map with all children that need to be removed
  const updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
  return ref.update(updates);
});
```

I have already tried to get the value of "image" but I have `No such object: XXXXX.appspot.com/https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/undefined/image`

Thank you in advance for your help.

## EDIT#1

Thanks to Doug Stevenson, I changed the value of "image" for having the good path.

## EDIT#2

Thank you Ralemos, I iterate it with a foreach but now I have a new error : Error: No such object: XXXXX.appspot.com/https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/-M9OeGPXB-KqEVqxZYCb/image And I don't understand why because the value is not null.

Comment: Your image string is a download URL generated by a client SDK for Cloud Storage.  However, the Admin SDK for Cloud Storage doesn't understand these download URLs.  I suggest storing a normal path to the file and using that to delete the object instead.  For example: /path/to/image.jpg

Comment: Okay, thank you, I’ll see about the path, and for the UID, do you have a suggestion or any solution ? Thank you.

Comment: Doug's comment already offers a solution for you issue with the path of the file you want to delete in the bucket. I did not understood what problem you are facing with the UID, since by what you wrote on the question it only references the deletion of files, can you clarify?

Comment: In my question I said I couldn’t get the value of "image" because I can’t get the UID.
I make a request for the "timestamp" and I need the UID of it but cannot get it and I need it to get the value of "image". I hope that’s clear enough for you

Comment: From what I understood of your code, your `oldItemsQuery` variable is a list of all the documents that need to be deleted, ordered by timestamp, correct? If that is the case, why don't you iterate it with a foreach for example? With that, you get each individual document uid of this list and do whatever you need to do with it that value.

Comment: Thank you Ralemos, I iterate it with a foreach but now I have a new error : ``Error: No such object: XXXXX.appspot.com/https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/-M9OeGPXB-KqEVqxZYCb/image `` And I don't understand why because the value is not null

Comment: Is `XXXXX.appspot.com/https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/-M9OeGPXB-KqEVqxZYCb/image` your object or it's value? If it is the value, this is weird, cause you appear to have part of a storage path (`XXXXX.appspot.com`) and a url (`https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/-M9OeGPXB-KqEVqxZYCb/image`) in the same value. This could be part of the issue. Also, can you share the code changes you made? This would make it easier to find what the issue is.

Comment: This is my object and the value is "/photo-send......", I edit the code in my post.

Comment: Can you share an example image url from your storage? I don't see how you can reach it on storage with the information you currently have stored, woudn't it be easier to create a field called imageUrl in your Firestore and store the url in there?