# Delete child after certain amount of time, Firebase function

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want a child to be deleted after a certain amount of time. The data of the child is stored in multiple Firebase collections and I know nothing about .js (JavaScript!?). The idea is to remove the child after 2 hours automatically, without the user having to do anything additionally.. is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You say "child", which is a term from Realtime Database, but also "collections" which is a Firestore term. Which of the two are you using?

Comment: For Realtime Database it'd be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours. For Firestore it'd be the same setup, but then against the Firestore API.

Comment: How are you going to make sure that the device is connected when the app is supposed to delete a record?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am talking about the Realtime Database. Sorry for the confusion due to the wording "collection"...

Comment: @ElTomato App is only working when connected to the internet..

Comment: In that case I'd recommend porting the code from my answer here to Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours. If you're struggling with a specific piece of that conversion, share what you tried and we'll try to help.