# How do you delete a document by timestamp in firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firestore Database Image]

So I am trying to make a chat app with cloud Firestore and I don't how to delete a document by timestamp.

This is currently how I delete a document.but when I tried it deletes all the document:

```
onLongPress: () async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(
          groupChatId)
      .collection(
      groupChatId)
      .orderBy("timestamp",descending: true).get().then((value) => {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds in value.docs){
          ds.reference.delete()
        }
  });
},
```

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours

Comment: Are you sure that `groupChatId` holds the correct value? Besides that, do you have the propper rules set?

Comment: yes, i just need how to get the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(
          groupChatId)
      .collection(
      groupChatId)
      .where("timestamp", isLessThan: DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch-TheNumberOfMicrosencundenTheDocumentCanBeOld).get().then((value) => {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds in value.docs){
          ds.reference.delete()
        }
  });
```