# Deleting buckets after a week they where created

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Realtime Database, is it possible to automatically delete buckets some time after they are created? (Let's say a week.)

Comment: Can you please define "bucket"? The term is usually used in "Firebase Storage" that is a different product than Realtime Database. Please share any screenshots that might help.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge in this matter is so low. When I store some value, a "folder" is created inside the main "folder" of the project. What I want is delete automatically this "sub folders" after a certain period of time. Thanks.

Comment: If you referring to some nodes of the the databases then checkout: [Firebase delete data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours)